# Generator Functions being called from a normal function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting confused on generator expression in python..

I was toying around an idea... say I have a generator function that is being called by a normal function with a normal return statement..

```
def stream_something():
    for x in range(10):
        yield x

def return_something():
    return stream_something()

return_generator = return_something()
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
```

I was expecting something like this since in the method return_something, I was thinking that I would be getting a new instance of the stream_something generator function.

> 0 0 0 0

But I am getting this value..looks like

> 0 1 2 3 4

I am just confused maybe but could someone enlighten me up on this?
So does it mean that even if I used a return statement, it is still yielding me up some value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` gets the nest value of the sequence whereas you're yielding the range of 0 to 10, so of course, the `next` will return the next value, unsurprisingly, that's why it's called `next`, if you had this code:

```
def stream_something():
    for x in range(10):
        yield 0 # Notice!

def return_something():
    return stream_something()

return_generator = return_something()
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
print(next(return_generator))
```

It would continuously print `0`.

Comment: Ohh yes...silly me, I am still using the same generator function.  I should not be mixing the return and yield in python functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`yield` is used to return a Generator which is also an Iterator in a lazy way.
Your code with type hint would be:

```py
def stream_something() -> Iterator[int]:
  ...

def return_something() -> Iterator[int]:
  ...
```

`return_something` returns the same `Iterator` returned by `stream_something`.